Debugger in Qt Creator not displaying values correctly
For some context regarding my issue, my configuration is the following:

Qt Creator version : 9.0.2
Qt version : 5.15.8
Qt Kit : Replacement for "Dekstop Qt 6.6.2 GCC 64 bit"
C++ 11
OS : Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

When debugging my project using Qt, I am not able to see the actual values of my variables. Instead, I have some pointers and memory addresses. (see picture attached)
I have tried to toggle on "use debugger assistance" as specified in this post. I have also tried to clean and recompile after changing this option but it didn't help.
Any idea on how can this be fixed ?
EDIT (solved):
The variables I could not display were only the ones from Qt (i.e. QString, etc...).
I managed to solve it with this post thanks to Snowdrop in this post.

I had exactly the same problem in the same Qt Creator version in the equivalent Devuan distribution (5.0 "Daedalus"). If it isn't clear from the edit it is due to bug in that version of the Qt IDE. The fix requires two simple patches to the files in /usr/share/qtctreator/debugger - as discussed in QTCREATORBUG-28659 - you need to apply the pretty-printers.patch as posted in this message.
It makes a single change to each of two files - dumper.py and gdbbridge.py.
